# onError always internal server error

Tags: java, httpresponse, grpc, grpc-java

I am running a java grpc server. I want a 404 resource not found error when the client calls for a resource that does not exist, but instead I'm getting a wrapped up 500 server error in rest calls, and 200 in grpc client calls.

The response to the caller from a rest endpoint looks like:

```
"status":500,"error":"Internal Server Error","exception":"io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException","message":"NOT_FOUND: Mapping not found."
```

And the server produces:

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: NOT_FOUND: Mapping not found.] with root cause
    io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: NOT_FOUND: Mapping not found.
```

What I would like is the client to get a 404 error code. Is this possible?

Code:

```
@Override
public void getMyObjectData(DataRequest request, StreamObserver<DataResponse> responseObserver) {
    String input = request.getData();
    if(/* Check if input exists in back end */) {
        String data = /* Retrieve data */
        DataResponse response = DataResponse
                                  .newBuilder()
                                  .setData(data)
                                  .build();

        responseObserver.onNext(response);
        responseObserver.onCompleted();
    }
    else {
        responseObserver.onError(Status.NOT_FOUND.withDescription("Mapping not found.").asException());
    }
}
```

Using a gRPC client the following is returned:

`headers=GrpcHttp2ResponseHeaders[:status: 200, content-type: application/grpc, grpc-status: 5, grpc-message: Mapping not found.]`

The client code:

```
public void getData(String input) {
    DataRequest request = DataRequest
                                .newBuilder()
                                .setInput(input)
                                .build();
    DataResponse response;
    try {
        response = blockingStub.getData(request);
    }
    catch (StatusRuntimeException e) {
        LOG.error("RPC failed: {}", e.getMessage());
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: How exactly do you call the gRPC method? If it is with a gRPC client, there is no HTTP error code. It seems like you have some service in between, e.g. a HTTP1 JSON service which then calls the gRPC service.

Comment: @DominikSandjaja I have edited the question to include the client code that generated the output.

Comment: I still don't see where you wrap you gRPC call in a REST call. Where and how do you call `getMyObjectData(...)`?

Comment: @DominikSandjaja Inside the `@Configuration` class there is a `@Bean` annotation for a class called `ServiceImplementation`, which extends the class `ServiceGrpc.ServiceImplBase`, which is generated from a proto file.